# how to get the guild that have less than 10 members using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, nodes

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
  if (message.guild.memberCount <= 10) {
    message.channel.send (guild.name)
  }
else return;
  });
    }
}
```

This code only show the total guild name but i want to get guild that have less than 10 member

Comment: Your logic is correct, could you send the output? Attach it with your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fairly easy.

```
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
        if (channel.type === 'text' && !targetChannel && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) targetChannel = channel
    })


  if(guild.memberCount < 10 ) {
     //code
  }
```

Comment: Please learn how you can answer to a question as answers just writing 'this is fairly easy' do not help the user. You must explain what everything is defined as, otherwise there would be no point on answering. Thanks

Comment: Its ok i can understand it and it was ez xd

Answer (score 0):

```
<client>.guilds.cache.filter(guild=>guild.members.cache.size < 10).map(guild=>guild.name).join('\n');
```

The snippet above uses:
`<client>` which is your Discord.Client.

`<client>.guilds.cache.filter` filters something from the guilds that your bot client is in. The filter, `guild=>guild.members.cache.size < 10` is filtering all guilds to guilds with less than 10 members in them. The `.map` function maps out the filtered map, and the `.join('\n')` joins the array into a list, split by paragraph breaks.

You can either evaluate the snippet using an eval command or you can place that in a command template.

Hope this helped, if anything fails to work, please comment and I'll try my best to answer!